# Оптимизировать программу

Tags: python, tkinter, оптимизация

Написал программу, предназначенную для того, чтобы обводить мышкой контуры изображения. Таким образом, образуется набор точек, координаты которых я и вывожу в результирующий файл. В программе присутствует функционал, позволяющий перемещать изображение по зажатии средней кнопки мыши. Соответственно, и сами точки должны двигаться. Реализовал перемещение как изображения, так и точек (в коде функция `on_mouse_middle_motion`). Однако, видимо, ужасно реализовал, так как, чем больше точек на изображении, тем перемещение происходит более прерывисто. Двигаю объекты с помощью встроенного метода tkinter-объекта canvas.move(айди объекта, координаты смещения). Каким образом оптимизировать программу, чтобы можно было перемещать все объекты без лагов, даже если объектов много? Принимаю любую помощь, вплоть до "*А зачем тебе для этой задачи tkinter? Лучше используй ...*" или "*Вот в этом месте кода тебе стоило сделать так ...*"

привожу код файлов main.py, geometry.py, drag.py, соответственно

спасибо за вашу помощь

[image: скрин программы]

```
#main.py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from geometry import * # свой файл
from drag import * # свой файл
from math_functions import * # свой файл
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

brush_size = 3
color = "#70a1ff"


def load_image():
    global img
    global image

    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="D:\\Progs\\WebProgs\\FurierTest\\Images",
                                               title="Select A File")  # , filetypes=(("png files", ("*.png"))))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    canvas.delete(image)
    image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=NW)
    path.clear()


def on_mouse_left_click_enter(event):
    global brush_size
    global color

    curr_point = Point(event.x, event.y)

    path.append(curr_point)
    path.vertexes[-1].draw(canvas)


def on_mouse_left_click_moving(event):
    global brush_size
    global color

    curr_point = Point(event.x, event.y)

    if curr_point.dist(path.vertexes[-1]) > 10:
        path.append(curr_point)
        path.vertexes[-1].draw(canvas)


eraser_cursor = Point(0, 0)
eraser_mode = False


def on_mouse_right_click_enter(event):
    global eraser_cursor
    global eraser_mode

    path.change_radiuses(4)
    path.redraw()

    eraser_cursor = Point(event.x, event.y, radius=5)
    eraser_cursor.draw(canvas, fill=None)

    eraser_mode = True


def on_mouse_right_click_moving(event):
    global eraser_cursor
    global eraser_mode

    for vertex in path.vertexes:
        if vertex.dist(eraser_cursor) <= eraser_cursor.radius:
            path.delete(vertex)

    path.redraw()

    eraser_cursor.x = event.x
    eraser_cursor.y = event.y
    canvas.coords(eraser_cursor.obj_id, event.x - eraser_cursor.radius, event.y - eraser_cursor.radius,
                  event.x + eraser_cursor.radius, event.y + eraser_cursor.radius)


def on_mouse_right_click_exit(event):
    global eraser_cursor
    global eraser_mode

    path.change_radiuses(1.5)
    path.redraw()

    eraser_cursor.delete(canvas)
    eraser_mode = False


def on_backspace(event):
    path.clear()


def on_return(event):
    path.to_file("path.txt")


def on_mouse_middle_click(event):
    default_drag.start(event)


###############################################################################
def on_mouse_middle_motion(event):
    # default_drag - объект класса DragHandler из файла drag.py
    # path - объект класса Path из файла geometry.py
    # определены в main-участке в самом низу
    
    difference = default_drag.drag(obj_id=image, event=event) # метод перемещает объект с айди obj_id и возвращает вектор (в моей реализации - Point) того, на сколько переместили
    path.move(difference) # метод класса Path (не путать с одноименным методом tkinter-объектов)
###############################################################################


def on_mouse_wheel(event):
    if eraser_mode:
        # respond to Linux or Windows wheel event
        if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
            eraser_cursor.radius -= 10
        if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
            eraser_cursor.radius += 10

        eraser_cursor.radius = MathFunctions.clamp(eraser_cursor.radius, 2, 500)

        eraser_cursor.delete(canvas)
        eraser_cursor.draw(canvas, fill=None)


root = Tk()
root.title("pathER")

img = PhotoImage(file="D:\\Progs\\WebProgs\\FurierTest\\images\\cheetah.png")

# canvas
canvas = Canvas(width=img.width(), height=img.height(), bg='#323232')
canvas.pack()

image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=NW)

# events
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", on_mouse_left_click_enter)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_mouse_left_click_moving)

canvas.bind("<Button-3>", on_mouse_right_click_enter)
canvas.bind("<B3-Motion>", on_mouse_right_click_moving)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", on_mouse_right_click_exit)

canvas.bind("<BackSpace>", on_backspace)
canvas.bind("<Return>", on_return)
canvas.bind("<Button-2>", on_mouse_middle_click)
canvas.bind("<B2-Motion>", on_mouse_middle_motion)

canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", on_mouse_wheel)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    default_drag = DragHandler(canvas)
    path = Path(canvas)

    export_button = Button(root, text="Export", command=path.to_file, bg="#1dd1a1", fg="#222f3e")
    clear_button = Button(root, text="Clear", command=path.clear, bg="#ff6b6b", fg="#222f3e")
    load_image_button = Button(root, text="Load image", command=load_image, bg="#ffeaa7", fg="#222f3e")

    export_button.pack()
    clear_button.pack()
    load_image_button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

```
# geometry.py
import math


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius=1.5):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.radius = radius

        self.obj_id = -1

    def draw(self, canvas, outline="#ff7675", fill="#ff7675"):
        self.obj_id = canvas.create_oval(self.x - self.radius, self.y - self.radius, self.x + self.radius, self.y + self.radius, outline=outline, fill=fill)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y
        return self

    def __isub__(self, other):
        self.x -= other.x
        self.y -= other.y
        return self

    def __mul__(self, value):
        return Point(self.x * value, self.y * value)


    def dist(self, other):
        return (self - other).length()

    def length(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y)

    def show(self):
        print("[{}, {}]".format(self.x, self.y))

    def is_near(self, other):
        return self.dist(Point(other.x, other.y)) <= self.radius

    def delete(self, canvas):
        canvas.delete(self.obj_id)


class Path:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.vertexes = []
        self.canvas = canvas

    def append(self, point):
        self.vertexes.append(point)

    def clear(self):
        for vertex in self.vertexes:
            self.canvas.delete(vertex.obj_id)
        self.vertexes = []

    def redraw(self):
        for vertex in self.vertexes:
            self.canvas.delete(vertex.obj_id)
            vertex.draw(self.canvas)

    def pop(self):
        deleted_point = self.vertexes.pop()
        self.canvas.delete(deleted_point.obj_id)

    def to_file(self, filename="path.txt"):
        file = open(filename, "w")

        for vertex in self.vertexes:
            file.write("{}, {}\n".format(vertex.x, vertex.y))

        file.close()

    def move(self, direction):
        for vertex in self.vertexes:
            vertex += direction
            self.canvas.move(vertex.obj_id, direction.x, direction.y)

        #self.redraw()


    def change_radiuses(self, value):
        for vertex in self.vertexes:
            vertex.radius = value

    def delete(self, vertex):
        self.canvas.delete(vertex.obj_id)
        self.vertexes.remove(vertex)
```

```
# drag.py
from geometry import *


class DragHandler:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas

        self.begin = Point(0, 0)
        self.end = Point(0, 0)
        self.difference = Point(0, 0)

    def start(self, event):
        self.begin = Point(event.x, event.y)
        self.difference = Point(event.x, event.y)

    def drag(self, obj_id, event):
        self.end = Point(event.x, event.y)
        self.difference = self.end - self.begin

        self.canvas.move(obj_id, self.difference.x, self.difference.y)

        self.begin = Point(event.x, event.y)

        return self.difference
```

Comment: Код не читал - многовато тут, но наверняка надо отделить процесс изменения рисунка от его отображения. Ну, сделать отображение раз в какое-то время, а на движения мыши просто менять сами объекты, но не отрисовывать. Ну, если там такое вообще возможно.

Comment: @CrazyElf    а чем лаги отличаются от отображения раз в секунду ? ниочень вариант

Answer (score 0):

в данной ситуации лучше  заместо `canvas.move` использовать мой код для движения канваса а не обьектов это будет гораздо быстрее

```
 canvas.configure(xscrollincrement=1) #чтобы двигать канвас по пикселям
 canvas.xview_scroll(-5, "units")  #движения канваса по иксу
 canvas.xview_scroll(5, "units") #движения канваса по игрику
```